# ROS Answers SE migration: What is tf2?

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [wiki page for tf2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf2) doesn't give any obvious indication that tf2 is experimental, though I can imply that by the fact that it's in the [geometry_experimental](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry_experimental) stack. Regardless, I'm curious about how tf2 differs from tf, how far along in the development process it is, if it is targeted to replace tf at some point and if so when, etc.

**EDIT**: Another [relevant page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/geometry/Roadmap), though it doesn't quite answer the questions I have.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10810/what-is-tf2?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf2 is a rewrite of tf.  Our goal at the moment is to release it into Fuerte.  It is targeted to replace tf.  It is mostly a redesign for easier use in code.  It's also noteably lower overhead and doesn't require anywhere near as many dependencies.  The design page can be found at [tf2/Design](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf2/Design).

It is backwards compatible with tf on the ROS interface thus tf and tf2 can work side by side.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-03**:
Thanks. I take it then that such things as having an undirected (but still acyclic) graph of frames, and not having to continually broadcast static transforms, would be off the table as they would break the ROS interface?